Kernel dimension is preserved under uniform convergence of bounded operators on a Hilbert space
I hope you can help me with the following question. Consider a sequence $C_{n}$ of bounded operators on an infinite-dimensional separable complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ that converges uniformly to $C$, a bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$ (the domain of the operators is all $\mathcal{H}$). This is,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Vert C_{n}-C\Vert =0
$$
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is the norm of $\mathcal{H}$.
Suppose that for all $n$, $dimKer(C_{n})=k$ with $k$ finite and positive . My question is, can it be proven that $dimKer(C)=k$ ? some hypotheses are missing? or is there a counterexample?
For the proof, take an orthonormal basis $\left\lbrace y^{i}_{n}\right\rbrace _{i=1}^{k}$ for each subspace $Ker(C_{n})$ and for the Banach-Alaoglu theorem for every $i=1,...,k$ there exists a subsequence of $y^{i}_{n}$ that weakly converges to $y^{i}$ in $\mathcal{H}$. One goal is to show that $\left\lbrace y^{i}\right\rbrace _{i=1}^{k} $ is an orthonormal basis for $Ker(C)$.
Until now I have not been able to see if at least the vectors $y^{i}$ are in $Ker(C)$. I would like to know if the sequence $C_{n}y^{i}_{n}$ has a subsequence that converges in either the weak or strong sense to $Cy^{i}$ for each $i=1,...,k$.
I would appreciate a good suggestion. Thank you for your time.

For any bounded operator $C$, then $\frac 1n C$ converges uniformly to the $0$ operator. So the kernel dimension is not preserved.

Fix any $T$ such that $\dim \ker T=k$, and let $C_n=\frac1n\,T$. Then $\dim\ker C_n=k$ for all $n$, but $C_n\to0$, so the kernel of the limit is infinite-dimensional.
Worse, you can prescribe $\dim \ker C_n$ for all $n$, and still have uniform convergence to an operator. Suppose you have numbers $\{k(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ of $H$. Let $P_r$ be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $\{e_1,\ldots,e_r\}$. Put
$$
C_n=\frac1n\,(I-P_{k(n)}).
$$
Then $\ker C_n=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_{k(n)}\}$, so $\dim\ker C_n=k(n)$. And $\|C_n\|=\frac1n$, so $C_n\to0$ uniformly.

The conclusion does not follow the opposite way. Assume $T$ is the operator defined by $Te_n=2^{-n}e_n,$ where $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis. For fixed $m$ choose  a sequence of subsets $A_k$  of $\mathbb{N}$ so that $\#\{A_k\}=m$ and  $\inf A_k\to\infty.$  Let $T_k$ be defined as $T_ke_n=2^{-n}e_n$ for $n\notin A_k$ and $T_ke_n=0$ for $n\in A_k.$ Then $T_k\to T,$ but $T$ is injective while $\dim\ker T_k=m.$
